# ScrollablePositionedList is rebuilding forms while scrolling

Tags: flutter

I have a `ScrollablePositionedList` where I want to display several forms. However, while scrolling the form is getting rebuilt all the time and looses it's values.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BLACK',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyContent(List.generate(
            100,
            (index) => MyForm(
                  key: ValueKey('FORM$index'),
                ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  MyForm({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [TextFormField()],
        ));
  }
}

class MyContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<MyForm> forms;

  const MyContent(this.forms, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
      itemCount: forms.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => forms[index],
    );
  }
}
```

How can I prevent this rebuild?

I tried setting keys everywhere, but they don't seem to have an effect.

The only text that is always preserved is the very first item. It always keeps it's value.

Comment: Okay, I found a hack: `minCacheExtent: double.infinity` stops all rebuilds, because the list cache will be so big that nothing is gonna rebuild. But still not an optimal solution...